# Explicitly retrieving metdataStore

Tags: breeze

I have a view model that will always create a new entity (Score); it doesn't need to wait for nor query the repository to know this.

I (currently) want to create the new entity as the page loads and use it to populate the (KnockoutJS) view model.

I believe that the entity manager lazily populates the metadata and have spoofed the behavior I want by making an unnecessary query purely to force the metadata population. The API docs don't cover this:

http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#property_metadataStore

**Question**
Is there a way to force the manager to populate the metadata without issuing a redundant query?

Here's the spoofed code flattened to show its intent:

```
manager.executeQuery(redundantQuery).then(function(data) {
  var viewScore = manager.metadataStore.getEntityType("Score").createEntity();
  viewScore.ID(breeze.core.getUuid());
  viewScore.Value(57);
  ko.applyBindings(viewScore, $ViewScore);
}).fail(function(e){
  ...
})
```

I'd be happy with:

```
manager.metadataStore.then(function() {

})...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single MetadataStore can store metadata for multiple DataServices.  The manager.dataService is simply the 'default' DataService for an EntityManager, there may be others.